# Using Max to select latest Date

Tags: sql-server

I am joining 3 tables with a common column 'Load-Id' tables are OD. OH. and MD. MD has a EDI file that changes to another name when an electronic file is transmitted, therefore I need to only display the data returned from the last updated filename.

I have tried various groups and orders and then read up that I can create a new column joining the data to the last updated filename, using Join and Max date but keep on running into syntax errors

```
SELECT  TOP(100)PERCENT
    OD. *
    OH.[LOAD_ID] AS [OHLOADID],
    OH.[CARRIER],
    OH.[CLIENT_REF],
    MD.[LOAD_ID] AS [MDLOADID],
    MD.[MR_FILE] AS [POFILE]
        JOIN (SELECT MR_FILE, MAX(MR_DATE) AS [MDTRANDATE] 
        FROM dbo.mates_det MD 
        GROUP BY MR_FILE) MRD ON MD.MR_DATE = MRD.MR_DATE
FROM dbo.out_det OD
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.out_head OH ON OH.[LOAD_ID] = OD.[LOAD_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.mates_det ON MD.[LOAD_ID] = OD.[LOAD_ID]

    GROUP BY OD.PALLET_ID, OD.SEQ_NO 
    ORDER BY OD.PALLET_ID, OD.SEQ_NO
```

Return of 1 line per pallet ID and Sequence and now all data is duplicated if there is more than one MRfile name. 
The name starts with PO and then the location number 244 and then the number of the zip file that contains the electronic data. In other words
PO2440001.000.zip
PO2440002.000.zip
and so on. when PO2449999.000.zip is reached the file numbering starts again from PO2440001.000.zip and that is why I make use of the MRfile date.

From the comments the error message is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 118 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'JOIN'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 120 Incorrect syntax near
>   'MRD'.

Comment: I forgot to post the error:

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 118
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 120
Incorrect syntax near 'MRD'.

Comment: It looks like the three lines starting with `JOIN (SELECT MR_FILE, MAX(MR_DATE) AS [MDTRANDATE]` should be moved down to the `from` clause

Comment: @PhilipKelley is right - the select where you're getting the latest date for `MR_File` is syntactically incorrect.  If you edit your question to include the table DDL, some sample data, and the expected output (as text, please) we can help you get that sorted out.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT 
              OD. *
            , OH.[LOAD_ID]      AS [OHLOADID]
            , OH.[CARRIER]
            , OH.[CLIENT_REF]
            , MD.[LOAD_ID]      AS [MDLOADID]
            , MD.[MR_FILE]      AS [POFILE]
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  OD.PALLET_ID, OD.SEQ_NO
                                ORDER BY MD.MR_DATE DESC) AS rn
        FROM dbo.out_det OD
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.out_head  OH ON OH.[LOAD_ID] = OD.[LOAD_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.mates_det MD ON MD.[LOAD_ID] = OD.[LOAD_ID]
  ) X
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY X.PALLET_ID, X.SEQ_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

An issue is this code:

```
MD.[MR_FILE] AS [POFILE]
    JOIN (SELECT MR_FILE, MAX(MR_DATE) AS [MDTRANDATE] 
    FROM dbo.mates_det MD 
    GROUP BY MR_FILE) MRD ON MD.MR_DATE = MRD.MR_DATE
```

You put `MRD.MR_DATE` as a join condition.  But when you did aggregation you gave the MR_DATE column the column alias AS `[MDTRANDATE]`.

So you have to use the alias you specified:

```
MD.[MR_FILE] AS [POFILE]
    JOIN (SELECT MR_FILE, MAX(MR_DATE) AS [MDTRANDATE] 
    FROM dbo.mates_det MD 
    GROUP BY MR_FILE) MRD ON MD.MR_DATE = MRD.[MDTRANDATE]
```